# Can I create VLANs when there are subnets already?

Tags: networking, vlan, subnet

I need to have separate subnets in each room but at the same time, I need a few computers (spread across rooms in different subnets) to be in a single VLAN. Is it possible or do I need to rework the whole design?

Comment: VLAN's are not the same things a subnets. Please refer to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/difference-between-subnet-and-vlan for differences between the two.

Comment: @Rex Sure they are not the same, this is why I ask the question. I need both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it depends on your network design on how you implement it.

- You can do it statically and just assign the ports where the computers are located that you need in the same VLAN to the VLAN.
- You can use dynamic VLAN's which, as Yarik Dot already posted, assigns the VLAN to a computer dynamically on 802.1X authentication, based on MAC Address, based on logged on User, or possible other attributes that your Infrastructure may support

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) says:

> **Establishing VLAN memberships**[edit]
>
> The two common approaches to assigning VLAN membership are as follows:
>   Static VLANs Dynamic VLANs
>
> Static VLANs are also referred to as port-based VLANs. Static VLAN
>   assignments are created by assigning ports to a VLAN. As a device
>   enters the network, the device automatically assumes the VLAN of the
>   port. If the user changes ports and needs access to the same VLAN, the
>   network administrator must manually make a port-to-VLAN assignment for
>   the new connection.
>
> Dynamic VLANs are created through the use of software. With a VLAN
>   Management Policy Server (VMPS), an administrator can assign switch
>   ports to VLANs dynamically based on information such as the source MAC
>   address of the device connected to the port or the username used to
>   log onto that device. As a device enters the network, the switch
>   queries a database for the VLAN membership of the port that device is
>   connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I am sorry, I don't know exact terminology, however newer ciscos support dynamic vlans.

It can change VLAN on port according to some authentication - possibly even mac address.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's not clear what you would like to do.
Lets say You have 3 rooms, and you want all of them have a separate subnet?

- Room 1: 192.168.1.1...254 /24 subnet
- Room 2: 192.168.2.1...254 /24 subnet
- Room 3: 192.168.3.1...254 /24 subnet

There you have all three rooms with a different subnets. But to be able to communicate you need to have a gateway in each subnet that connects them together.

If you want to add VLANs, then what you will be able to do is lets say room1pc1 moves to room2 and you want to use room1's network (192.168.1.1/24) in room2 where the network is 192.168.2.1/24 then you need to change room1pc1's switchport to the Vlan that handles traffic for room1.

So you will have:

- Room 1: 192.168.1.1...254 /24 subnet - VLAN1
- Room 2: 192.168.2.1...254 /24 subnet - VLAN2
- Room 3: 192.168.3.1...254 /24 subnet - VLAN3

And the PCs:

- PC1 in Room2 with VLAN1 = 192.168.1.X
- PC2 in Room2 with VLAN2 = 192.168.2.X
- PC3 in Room1 with VLAN1 = 192.168.1.X
- PC4 in Room3 with VLAN3 = 192.168.3.X

So you will be able to manage network subnets no matter what room they are in. You will be able to give them their own subnet in whatever room they are in. Even if they sit next to each other.